# .htaccess in subdirectory - how to use RewriteBase

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, server, apache2

I'm trying the following.

I have this directory structure, which is available in our network at IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

```
root
    -dir1
    -dir2
    -dir3
```

Now in my dir1-folder, I have a site that uses the following .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dir1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

On my site, I am linking the sources and pages with a preceding "/", like "/details" or "/css/app.css"

The problem is, that the links always go to the root folder because of the preceding "/".

What can I do to make the links "stay" in the subdirectory without having to edit all links and sources?

I have tried to use

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteBase /dir1
RewriteBase /dir1/
RewriteBase dir1
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Remove leading slash from target: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, but that didn't work either... :(

Comment: There is no way it cannot work unless you have some other rule/config not shown here.

Answer (score 3):

[`RewriteBase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) doesn't change anything, because it applies only to relative path targets.

> The RewriteBase directive specifies the URL prefix to be used for per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule directives that *substitute a relative path*.

Because your target is already the absolute `/index.php`, you can omit `RewriteBase` altogether.

---

From the given .htaccess, it seems index.php returns the requested files. So in this case, I would just prefix the path with the appropriate directory, e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=/dir1/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

or maybe give an additional argument, if this works better with the script, like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1&subdir=dir1 [NC,L,QSA]
```